# Add three dots at the end of my excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

My template function outputs just a limited excerpt and there is not three dots(...) at the end of it. How can I add dots? My function is like this:

```
function mts_excerpt($limit) {
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    }
    $excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
    $new_content = strip_tags($excerpt);
    return $new_content;
}
```

Comment: what is no(...) ?

Comment: I mean there aren't 3 dots at the end of my excerpts. And I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function mts_excerpt($limit) {
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
    }
    $excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
    $excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
    $new_content=$excerpt.". . .";
    return $new_content;
}
```

Only solution I can think of:

```
$excerpt = strip_tags($excerpt);
$new_content=$excerpt.". . .";
```

Comment: Just updated answer just have to rename a variable. Please check answer